# Laravel 5.5 ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

For some reason my jQuery refuses to load. I am getting an error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

My template is in `views/layouts/editor.blade.php` and  I am loading jQuery in the head of my template like this

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

I can see that jQuery is loaded in my console. but still I get the error.

I am compiling my javascript using laravel mix and my webpack.mix.js file looks like this:

```
// javascript
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/js')
   .autoload({
        jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
    });
// css
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'public/css');
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

My template file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

        <script>
            $(function(){
                alert();
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>


        @yield('content')

        <!-- Scripts -->

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If I look in my console I see the following

[image]

If I open the jquery.min.js file in a new tab I see the following:

[image]

So it's jquery underneath all that webpack boilerplate stuff.

I have also run `npm run production` which removes all that webpack stuff and leaves the raw jquery.

Comment: Tried `window.$` ?

Comment: I'm sorry Jonathan, I don't quite understand!

Comment: `"I can see that jQuery is loaded in my console. but still I get the error."` - What else can you see in your browser's debugging tools?  If you put a breakpoint on that line, *is* `$` defined there?  Is your jQuery library broken in some way?  Are you loading jQuery *after* trying to use it?  Loading it in a different or more confined scope?  The error is what it is... `$` is not defined.  Can you provide a complete but minimal example to demonstrate the problem and indicate why in that example it *should* be defined?

Comment: I have no idea what the `autoload` method does. I assume it's binding jquery to variables. Depending on how you're using jQuery, perhaps you want to try binding it to `window` as well, like `window.jQuery`.

Comment: I have updated my post with some more details.

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery separately? It ships with this in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` which is included in `app.js`. Same thing goes for loading bootstrap... this comes in app.scss. I would be using the `mix()` method for the assets you are mixing... like `mix('/js/app.js')`

Answer (score 6):

Try this.
In your view file create a section under content section

```
@section('scripts')

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
       $(function(){
            alert();
        });
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

@endsection
```

Then  @yield('scripts') just under the   @yield('content') in your template file.
So its looks like

```
    <body>

        @yield('content')

        <!-- Scripts -->

       @yield('scripts')

    </body>
```

Comment: I have the script tags that load the jquery assets / CDN in my header. adding the 'section' in the layout and the 'yield' in the template did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use mix.combine() instead mix.js() :

```
mix.combine([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
],'public/js/outputFile.js');
```

Comment: This answer helped me out, thanks! But I'm not sure what the difference is between mix.combine() and mix.js(). I can't seem to find it in the Laravel documentation. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I was compiling my jquery from the node_modules/jquery/dist folder instead of the /src folder.