# jquery not working even after including app.js before script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

My package.json file has devDependency for jquery as

```
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
```

I ran an npm install, build and then npm run dev after that.

My default blade template file has the scripts loading in the bottom as

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>

@yield('js')
```

and I am using javascript in my view as

```
@section('js')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#centerhead').click(function(){
                alert('test js');
            });
        });
    </script>
@stop
```

yet I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`error on the console when I am trying to use jQuery. Javascript works fine though.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939027/laravel-5-5-referenceerror-is-not-defined ... check where in the node_modules you're loading jquery from and if you're binding $ to the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. After runing the npm install jquery was installed in the node modules folder. I had to write `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')` in my bootstrap.js file. After that I ran an npm run dev and things started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try below in your blade file.

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

which frontend framework you are using?

Comment: I am using blade which came with the laravel. I actually do not have jquery in my resources folder. Even after doing an npm install I only get that inside the node modules folder only.